# SCCM app install method

Tags: windows-server-2008, sccm

I was wondering if it was possible to have SCCM install items on restart like msi's via GPO objects?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want to do an SCCM task sequence the only other option is to setup a scheduled task with the "At startup" trigger. You still need to perform an SCCM task sequence, but your only step would be to run "schtasks.exe". That would run the task at the next startup.

I must warn you in advance that the SCCM option that @newmanth suggested is a better choice in most cases. Scheduled task is more geared towards repetitive tasks that need to happen multiple times a year.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

Kvad,

I don't believe that you can set up an install to occur *ONLY* at startup, if that's what you mean.  You can, however, set up maintenance windows defining when an install can occur.  You can also force the install to occur, or simply allow the user that act at their convenience.

If you want a reboot immediately before the installer launches, set up the install as a task sequence.  As the first step, have the system restarted.  Then, run the app installed on the second step.